# Как преобразовать в целое число?

Tags: python, парсер, requests

помогите преобразовать response_json[0]['price_usd'] в целое число

```
import requests

TICKER_API_URL = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin'


response = requests.get(TICKER_API_URL)
response_json = response.json()

print(response_json[0]['price_usd'])
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

TICKER_API_URL = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin'


response = requests.get(TICKER_API_URL)
response_json = response.json()
price_s = response.json()[0]['price_usd']
price = int(price_s[:price_s.find('.')])
print(price)
```

Comment: Мое решение мне кажется проще (см. мой ответ).

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

TICKER_API_URL = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin'


response = requests.get(TICKER_API_URL)
response_json = response.json()

print(int(float(response_json[0]['price_usd'])))
```